# Python csv module splitting strings, not just fields

Tags: python, string, csv

When I run this input (saved as variable 'line'):

```
xsc_i,202,"House of Night",21,"/21_202"
```

through a csv reader:

```
for row in csv.reader(line):
    print row
```

it splits the strings, not just the fields

```
['x']
['s']
['c']
['_']
['i']
['', '']
['2']
['0']
['2']
['', '']
```

etc.

It exhibits this behavior even if I explicitly set the delimiter:

```
csv.reader(line, delimiter=",")
```

It's treating even strings as arrays, but I can't figure out why, and I can't just split on commas because many commas are inside "" strings in the input.

Python 2.7, if it matters.

Answer (score 6):

The first argument to [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is expected to be an iterable object containing csv rows. In your case the input is a string (which is also iterable) containing a single row. You need to enclose the `line` into a list:

```
for row in csv.reader([line]):
    print row
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> line = 'xsc_i,202,"House of Night",21,"/21_202"'
>>> for row in csv.reader([line]):
...     print row
... 
['xsc_i', '202', 'House of Night', '21', '/21_202']
```

Comment: Great, up-voted- if we change input as `>>> line = ''''xsc_i',202,"House of Night",21,"/21_202"'''` then it produce output as `["'xsc_i'", '202', 'House of Night', '21', '/21_202']
` , so question is why `'` is coming and why `"` is not coming in a output ?

Comment: @Clay Shrinky: why do you care about ' and "? You shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to see `re` in action.

```
import re
line='xsc_i,202,"House of Night",21,"/21_202"'
print map(lambda x:x.strip('"'),re.split(r',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)',line))
```

Output:`['xsc_i', '202', 'House of Night', '21', '/21_202']`

Answer (score 1):

This is because csv.reader expects

> any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string
>   each time its next() method is called

You have passed a string to the reader.

If you say:

```
line = ['xsc_i,202,"House of Night",21,"/21_202"',]
```

Your code should work as expected.
Please see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)